# crashed app after released in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have some app, and in the debugging mode it's work very well without crashed or something else,
but when I release it and install it in my real device it's work good, but just one screen when I clicked it the app is crashed, although in the debugging mode it's work without any issue!!

so how can I handle it?

Comment: can you show the android/build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

That happens in the software industry that what works on development and staging may not work in production or vice versa.

Now catching crashes and finding out root causes, I would suggest you to use some of the auto crash reporting tools like:

- Crashlytics
- Sentry

Now about Crashlytics, we've used it for the number of applications but based on my finding for the React Native application, that it will log native crashes but not the react native crashes, means that what you will find over Crashlytics is either android or iOS crashes.

About Sentry tool, they are saying that they have awesome support for the React Native but we need to check that whether it logs crashes of React Native code actually and not the native crashes!